# What happens if I interrupt local git process while a remote hook is running?

Tags: git, ssh

I have a `post-receive` hook set up on a remote machine which checks out a working copy of a website, installs latest dependencies, rebuilds some assets, and then restarts the HTTP daemon. So I can push code from my laptop to deploy the latest version of a site.

However, the hook can take a while to run. What will happen if I Ctrl-C the `git push` on my laptop *after* the changes have been received but *before* the hook finishes running? Will the hook script get interrupted remotely, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What will happen if I Ctrl-C the git push on my laptop after the changes have been received but before the hook finishes running?

Nothing special.  The hook's output to your end gets lost, so you can't see if it worked or not.  The hook itself still runs to completion, and if you write a sensible hook, it's already *logging* its results somewhere, as there's no guarantee that a person is watching the result now and will know what to do if it fails.

Answer (score 0):

It depends when the push is interrupted.

With Git 2.35 (Q1 2022), when the "[`git push`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4f7e2f0b212132a1807448a170ddca1def234137/Documentation/git-push.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push))</sup> command is killed while the receiving end is trying to report what happened to the ref update proposals, the latter used to die, due to [`SIGPIPE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#SIGPIPE).
The code now ignores `SIGPIPE` to increase our chances to run the post-receive hook after it happens.

See [commit d34182b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d34182b9e37fc72e04e40e834775a1c29e80c970) (10 Nov 2021) by [Robin Jarry (`rjarry`)](https://github.com/rjarry).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4f7e2f0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4f7e2f0b212132a1807448a170ddca1def234137), 15 Dec 2021)</sup>

> ### [`receive-pack`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d34182b9e37fc72e04e40e834775a1c29e80c970): ignore SIGPIPE while reporting status to client
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Robin Jarry</sup>

> Before running the post-receive hook, status info is reported back to the client.
> If a remote client exits before or during the status report, receive-pack is killed by SIGPIPE and post-receive is never executed.
>
> The post-receive hook is often used to send email notifications (see contrib/hooks/post-receive-email), update bug trackers, start automatic builds, etc.
> Not executing it after an interrupted yet "successful" push can lead to inconsistencies.
>
> Ignore SIGPIPE before reporting status to the client to increase the chances of post-receive running if pre-receive was successful.
> This does not guarantee 100% consistency but it should resist early disconnection by the client.